# API method to register new user in identityserver3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, identityserver3

I have an API proxy that do the rest of my business login, identityserver for authorization and Android Client.

I using implicit flow with the android client.

I request an access token from idsrv then make a request including this token to contact with the api and every things works correctly.

Now i want an API or any way to register new user instead of the default web page so i can use this APIs to create new users from my proxy or from my android app.

What is the better way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, by design, out of the scope of IdentityServer. You can build your own API that can update the user database for user provisioning.

Comment: thanks Brock, what about identity manager can i use it or is it deprecated now ?

Comment: IdMgr is meant for a dev or admin to quickly populate your user DB for dev/testing. If you want to use it in production, then that's up to you (but wasn't ever the design goal).